# Brief Structure of how the classes and interfaces are connected in java

Tags: class, object, structure

I was going through Class class and Object class. I just got stuck by the question that where getObject() method is located in java. Can anyone please tell me the brief structure that how built in classes and interfaces are connected in java?
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: class is nothing a blueprint of a object and there is no any concept of multiple inheritance so we are using interface in java

Comment: No, i am not asking that. I want to know that how the Java packages are connected through classes and interface.